# XML Parsing in Android not breaking to elements

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I have this following XML and i need to parse it in an Android app. I already constructed a parser that works pretty well but for XML formats like this http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6751304/Nicosia.xml

Now i have to parse something like this http://www.cytanet.com.cy/Services/connectivity/basic/wireless/GoogleMaps/wifimarkers.xml

the previous parser i used does not display any results. i get a blank loooooong list so i guess it reads the marker label. I also know that the xml is parsed because i can Log.e it in the logcat, but the elements are not read

Can someone recognize the formatting of the second XML file and point to a tutorial/info on how to parse it?

(I can post the current code if needed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use a SAX Parser, but you are looking for different attributes & different tags.

Looks like this article should get you started (Covers Sax parsing)
http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/android-xml-adventure-parsing-data-with-saxparser/

Basically in your StartElement you would grab the attributes
atts.getValue(MyAttribute.ID)

One reason for having both is something like this :
And to add to this.. One reason for having both would be to parse something like this :
Where you want to give an element an attribute which describes it.

```
<Contact>
    <Name>John Smith</Name>
    <PhoneNumber primary="true">
          <Number>214-555-1235</Number>
          <Type>Work</Type>
    </PhoneNumber>
    <PhoneNumber>
          <Number>214-555-1111</Number>
          <Type>Home</Type>
    </PhoneNumber>
</Contact>
```

Answer (score 2):

since your xml file is large is better that use sax parser .for using from sax parser you should use DeafaultHandler and in its startElement method you should write thing same following:

```
public void startElement(String arg0, String localName, String arg2,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    currentElement = true;

if (localName.equals("marker")) {

        String lat = attributes.getValue("lat");

        String  lng = attributes.getValue("lng");

        String city= attributes.getValue("city");

      //and ...

    }
}

   }
```